# how to use aggregate sum to create a new variable that is correct df size

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to create a new variable in this data set that is the total of the weights in each level of the cluster variable (i.e., sum of weights in cluster 1, cluster 2, etc.) I get this error, that weight_total must be size 8 or 1...and that the new variable size does not match the data frame size (4 vs. 8). How would I modify to create a new variable of size 8?

```
data.test <- data.frame(cluster = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
         weight = c(240, 240, 300, 300, 500, 500, 250, 250))


data.test <- data.test %>% mutate(weight_total = (aggregate(weight~cluster, data.test, FUN = sum)))

Caused by error:
! `weight_total` must be size 8 or 1, not 4.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to `group_by` the `cluster` variable, then add a variable which is the `sum` of `weights`.

```r
library(dplyr)

data.test %>%
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  mutate(weight_total = sum(weight))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#> # Groups:   cluster [4]
#>   cluster weight weight_total
#>     <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1       1    240          480
#> 2       1    240          480
#> 3       2    300          600
#> 4       2    300          600
#> 5       3    500         1000
#> 6       3    500         1000
#> 7       4    250          500
#> 8       4    250          500
```

Just as a demonstration, as of `dplyr 1.1.0` you can also group in the `mutate` operation.

```
data.test %>%
  mutate(weight_total = sum(weight), .by = cluster)
#>   cluster weight weight_total
#> 1       1    240          480
#> 2       1    240          480
#> 3       2    300          600
#> 4       2    300          600
#> 5       3    500         1000
#> 6       3    500         1000
#> 7       4    250          500
#> 8       4    250          500
```

Lastly, if you are trying to create a new data frame that's the total weights per cluster, you want to `summarize`.

```
data.test %>%
  summarize(weight_total = sum(weight),
            .by = cluster)
#>   cluster weight_total
#> 1       1          480
#> 2       2          600
#> 3       3         1000
#> 4       4          500
```